# How did Varys know about Jon Snow's parentage?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In S8E04, Tyrion makes a remark regarding Lyanna Stark leaving Robert Baratheon that only somebody who knew about Jon Snow's true parentage in the first place, could have made a connection between the two. And Varys does, as evidenced when he immediately asks Tyrion "how many people know".

So how did Varys know that Jon is a Targaryen?

Answer (score 9):

### Sansa told Tyrion and Tyrion told Varys

Sansa to Tyrion in Episode 4 when they were discussing what kind of ruler Dany would be.

> Tyrion. What if there's someone else? Someone better?

Comment: We never see Tyrion tell Varys. But it does look like he told him off screen after rewatching it

Comment: @83457, Yes, the scene is done in way where we step into an ongoing conversation IMO.

Comment: Possible ways Vary's could have known, 1) Vary's knows how to get information, he has his little birds. 2) Tyrion might have told him and they forgot to film it.

Comment: @StackOne He hasn't had his birds since Qyburn took them over.  And that this is the correct answer is so obvious from the episode that I'm astonished it required explanation.  But if you need more confirmation, the Inside the Episode feature specifically talks about Sansa playing 4-dimensional chess and feeding this information to Tyrion so that he'll then feed it to Varys, and then support will fall out from under Dany and head to Jon, without her needing to do anything more.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Yes it was very obvious that Sansa told Tyrion, but when I first saw the conversation with Tyrion and Varys it looked like Tyrion was starting the conversation with Varys. Hence why I thought Varys already knew.